# Gathering MFA status of users on Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to pull a list of users from Azure and see if they have MFA enabled or disabled (for reporting reason) currently I'm using the following:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred 

$users = Get-msoluser -All 
$users | select DisplayName,@{N='Email';E={$_.UserPrincipalName}},@{N='StrongAuthenticationRequirements';E={($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State)}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\csv.csv
```

This does connect as needed and pulls all user names and emails however `$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State` returns null. Is there another way or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `StrongAuthenticationRequirements` member on the return object [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0#outputs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below cmd

```
    Get-MsolUser -all | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ 
    if( $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne $null) {$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State} else { "Disabled"}}}
```

Using this script you can export result based on MFA status (ie,Users with enabled state/enforced state/disabled state alone.) along with their MFA authentication methods.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-reporting

It seems like I should actually be using

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0} | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName
```

The confusion was using `$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements` instead of `$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be more convenient to use the `Get-MsolUserByStrongAuthentication` function described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluserbystrongauthentication?view=azureadps-1.0

Answer (score 0):

To get just those that are disabled

```
Get-MsolUser -all | 
   select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{Name="MFA Status"; Expression={ 
    if($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -ne 0){ 
        $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements[0].State
    } else { 
        'Disabled'}
    }
} | where-Object -Property 'MFA Status' -eq Disabled | Sort-Object -Property 'DisplayName'
```